# What is difference between 'flutter build apk' and using gradle Ex) './gradlew build' or './gradlew assambleRelease' or etc?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm using flutter 2.2.3
and 3rd party obfuscation lib in android

When I run `flutter build apk`, it's not compelete(gradle failed)
But I move to android folder and run manually this command
`./gradlew assambleRelease;./gradlew obfuscation`, it is compelete

What is difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flutter build` is not use my local java SDK, It use bundle SDK in android.

But `./gradlew` is use my local java SDK.

My local environment java sdk version is 8 and android bundle SDK is 11.

When use `flutter build` command, java compiled use version 11.

When use `./gradlew` command, java compiled use version 8.